# Error: no se puede instalar el paquete react en un proyecto llamado react

Tags: reactjs, npm

Estoy configurando react, webpack, y babel, pero al momento de instalar react con el siguiente comando:

```
npm i react react-dom --save-dev
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "react" under a package
npm ERR! also called "react". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TecnologyStar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-06T23_45_47_061Z-debug.log
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si a alguien tal vez le paso el mismo error, ¿cuál fue la solución? Investigo pero aun no lo soluciono.

Comment: Hola Jhony, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir el comando que ejecutas y el log/errores en formato texto en lugar de como una imagen. Las imágenes no se indexan, no se pueden buscar y son menos accesibles. Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: El error pone que no se puede instalar el paquete react en un proyecto llamado react, ¿cómo se llama tu proyecto? Si es “react”, ¿puedes cambiarle el nombre para evitar el conflicto entre paquete y proyecto?

Comment: si amigo ya lo solucione no me e dado de cuenta de cambiar el nombre en mi packaje.json

Comment: Me alegro que lo solucionaras. Por favor, pon cuál era el problema y como lo solucionaste (con una pequeña descripción) en una respuesta y acéptala cuando pase el tiempo indicado. Lo menos que vas a conseguir es un +1 por mi parte. Saludos.

Comment: Podrías poner tu solución como respuesta a tu propia pregunta y obtener su voto por pregunta y respuesta.

Comment: No puedes poner el mismo nombre react a un proyecto react esa es la solución

Answer (score 0):

la forma mas comoda de crear un proyecto en react es usar npx create-react-app my-app ....
para ellos instalas de forma global create-react-app y lo ejecutas junto al nombre del proyecto.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app

Answer (score 0):

Las dependencias no te permiten crear un proyecto en un directorio llamado igual que la dependencia o framework, la solución es cambiar el nombre de la carpeta o directorio del proyecto.